# Does Presto have a function like translate()?

Tags: sql, presto, translate

I need to translate the special characters of a string column into 'raw' characters, using Amazon Presto.
In SQL Server, I could do that using the TRANSLATE function:

```
select
city_name,
translate(city_name,'áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚäëïöüÄËÏÖÜâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãẽĩõũÃẼĨÕŨ','aeiouAEIOUaeiouAEIOUaeiouAEIOUaeiouAEIOU') as cityname_raw
FROM cities
```

That would return exactly what I need:

### city_name

Goiânia
São Paulo
Palhoça
Várzea Paulista

### city_name_raw

Goiania
Sao Paulo
Palhoca
Varzea Paulista

Is there an alternative to the TRANSLATE() function in Amazon Presto?

## Update:

As suggested, I used lots of nested replaces and it worked out:

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(name,'ü','u'),'í','i'),'ê','e'),'ú','u'),'õ','o'),'ô','o'),'ç','c'),'é','e'),'ã','a'),'á','a'),'â','a'),'ó','o')
```

It isn't a pretty query but it works.

Comment: can always use a load of nested replaces

Comment: Yes, that seems like the only alternative. That is exactly how I worked it out.
It isn't a pretty query but it works. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

Trino (f.k.a as PrestoSQL) offers this functionality since Trino 337.

see https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#translate

Comment: This an an appalling deficit.  How would they forget to implement something like this, when such functionality exists in so many environments where ETL is needed?

Comment: @MichaelTuchman i updated the answer. The functionality has been implemented since my initial answer. Thanks for helping me keep this up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like this function. It can translate any special character you throw at it. Inspired by this solution:
[BigQuery: Convert accented characters to their plain ascii equivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43145902/bigquery-convert-accented-characters-to-their-plain-ascii-equivalents/44091906#comment82762620_44091906)

```sql
select regexp_replace(normalize('Goiânia, São Paulo, Palhoça, Várzea Paulista', NFD), '\pM')

-- result: 'Goiania, Sao Paulo, Palhoca, Varzea Paulista'
```

Basically you remove the "special character flag" from the digit.